# How to use DECIMAL(10,2) in prisma migrate tool?

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma

I need save `DECIMAL(10,2)` in database. In `MySQL` there is `DECIMAL` type.

MySQL docs:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html

Prisma 2.0 docs:

> https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-connectors/mysql

Possible Prisma 2.0 flows:

> https://www.prisma.io/docs/understand-prisma/introduction#typical-prisma-workflows

- I am using `Prisma Migrate` flow and see that mapping is constrained.
- I see that it can be done in `Introspection` flow.

#### Are there any plans of support mysql data types like `DECIMAL(10,2)` in `Prisma Migrate` flow?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Full support for native types has been added in [prisma/prisma@v2.15.0](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/2.15.0)

```js
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}
 
model Product {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  code String
  price Decimal @db.Decimal(9,2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently `prisma migrate` doesn't support the `Decimal` type. You can track the issue for custom DB types [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/446)

As a workaround, you would have to use a custom migration tool and specify the `Decimal` field that you require and then run `prisma introspect` which will get all the fields from your DB and populate the `schema.prisma`.